# Issue revtrieving 100 elements using the lower() function

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having issue retrieving info from a DB by using this query with the lower() function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "column_name" FROM "table" WHERE lower('car', 'house', 'plane'...) like '%owner%'
```

The query works with 1 attribute like for exmaple *'car'* but when I try to use 100 I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'lower'

What should I change in order to be able to use and output more than a single attribute?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the query you want is something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name
FROM yourTable
WHERE owner REGEXP 'car|house|plane';   -- and maybe other terms in the alternation
```

That is, you want to match all records where the `owner` column contains one of the substrings `car`, `house`, or `plane`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to check my question and I didn't explain myself well. I need to use '%owner%' since I'm searching for that word in a bunch of descriptions/text for each element I'm querying

Comment: No, you didn't explain that well.  Please include sample input and output data in your question above.

Comment: Already found a work around.Thanks a lot for your time.